# Django templates tag

Tags: python, django

I have a views.py returns a values as follows：

```
[{'host_id': 1, 'count': 8}, {'host_id': 3, 'count': 1}, {'host_id': 5, 'count': 3}]
```

how to use {% for %} ... {% endfor %} ... {% else %} tag on html?

If for loop does not match the value, a default value of 0 is set

This code is my guess ...

It seems not working , what should I do?

```
<tr>
    <td>
    {% for i in count_result %}
        {% if i.host_id == request.session.user.hid %}
            {{ i.count }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        0
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the function of `{% else %}` here? likes your code do not give all?

Comment: sorry , {% else %} is set a default value . This code is my guess ... It seems not working

Answer (score 1):

From the Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Loops over each item in an array, making the item available in a context variable. For example, to display a list of athletes provided in athlete_list:

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can loop over a list in reverse by using {% for obj in list reversed %}.

If you need to loop over a list of lists, you can unpack the values in each sublist into individual variables. For example, if your context contains a list of (x,y) coordinates called points, you could use the following to output the list of points:

```
{% for x, y in points %}
    There is a point at {{ x }},{{ y }}
{% endfor %}
```

This can also be useful if you need to access the items in a dictionary. For example, if your context contained a dictionary data, the following would display the keys and values of the dictionary:

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```